# SockJS connections will be closed when multiple connections open

Tags: spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket, sockjs

If only one SockJS (polling XHR) connection is open, then the app works fine. As soon as I additionally open it in a new window, then the connections will periodically be closed. The client is SockJS client, the backend is Spring Boot with MVC and SockJS enabled.

This is what I see on the server side:

```
2022-03-14 10:40:20.992 DEBUG 752 --- [nio-8311-exec-7] a.w.b.u.d.websocket.WebSocketHandler     : connection opened, id: gqgmlrff
2022-03-14 10:40:21.015 DEBUG 752 --- [nio-8311-exec-9] a.w.b.u.d.websocket.WebSocketHandler     : Server received message: {"action":"subscribe","payload":{"id":"c910f5d1-9e16-4e30-9559-e0e27973177b","entityType":"PROJEKT"}}
```

after 15-20 seconds

```
2022-03-14 10:40:40.075 DEBUG 752 --- [      SockJS-10] a.w.b.u.d.websocket.WebSocketHandler     : connection closed, sessionId: gqgmlrff, status: CloseStatus[code=3000, reason=Go away!]
```

This repeats infinitely with sessions of both windows.
It seems that the session closing will be initiated by the backend, since on client side the `.onclose()` handler will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that for both app instances different auth tokens have been generated and the equality wasn't updated. After updating `equals()` and hashCode() as follow the requests were correctly processed.

```kotlin
    override fun equals(obj: Any?): Boolean = obj is KeycloakToken &&
            principal == obj.principal &&
            authorities == obj.authorities &&
            isAuthenticated == obj.isAuthenticated


    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var code = 31
        for (authority in authorities) {
            code = code xor authority.hashCode()
        }
        code = code xor principal.hashCode()
        if (this.isAuthenticated) {
            code = code xor -37
        }
        return code
    }
```